# xpath dates comparison

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to filter elements based on an attribute that is a date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <article title="wired" pub-date="2010-11-22" />
  <article title="Plus 24" pub-date="2010-11-22" />
  <article title="Finance" pub-date="2010-10-25" />
</root>
```

My xpath attempt:

```
'//article[xs:date(./@pub-date) > xs:date("2010-11-15")]'
```

Using xpath 2.0 - would avoid adding a schema unless absolutely necessary.

**From comments**:

> I believe I must be missing something
>   then. Is it possible that I need to
>   specify something else for xs:date to
>   work? Maybe a xs: namespace
>   definition?

Comment: @Razor: What is the question? See no problem here, just style: a wouldn't use a starting `./` step, only for brevity one could use (for other expression) `.//` instead of `descendant::`.

Comment: Your XPath 2.0 expression should do, I would use `//article[xs:date(@pub-date) gt xs:date("2010-11-15")]` however which is a bit shorter and more compact.

Comment: Works for me in Oxygen/XML.  Why do you think this doesn't work?

Comment: I believe I must be missing something then. Is it possible that I need to specify something else for xs:date to work? Maybe a xs: namespace definition?

Comment: @Razor: Yes, yes, yes...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**In both XPath 1.0 and 2.0 you can use**:

```
//article[number(translate(@pub-date,'-','')) > 20101115]
```

**Your XPath 2.0 expression is correct, using Saxon 9.0.3 this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence select="//article[xs:date(./@pub-date) > xs:date('2010-11-15')]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
  <article title="wired" pub-date="2010-11-22" />
  <article title="Plus 24" pub-date="2010-11-22" />
  <article title="Finance" pub-date="2010-10-25" />
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<article title="wired" pub-date="2010-11-22"/>
<article title="Plus 24" pub-date="2010-11-22"/>
```

Comment: nice solution, +1 - it's a workaround tho, but will mark this as the answer if I cannot find what's wrong with my code

Comment: @Razor: I have updated my answer with a complete XSLT 2.0 solution showing that your XPath 2.0 expression *is* correct.

Comment: Not working even after adding an inline XML schema, so the issue has to be my xpath parser (velocity XMLtool). Your first solution *almost* works - you have an extra `)` before the closing `]`, please correct that and I'll mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<cfset startdatetime = Now() >
<cfset nNow = LSParseNumber(DateFormat(DateAdd('n', -15,startdatetime),'yyyyMMddHHmm')) >

number(substring(concat(translate(text(),'-: ',''),'0000000000000000'),1,12))<=#nNow#
```