# Perl Xpath: search item before a date year

Tags: perl, date, xpath

I have an xml database that contains films, for example:

```
<film id="5">
        <title>The Avengers</title>
        <date>2012-09-24</date>
        <family>Comics</family>
</film>
```

From a Perl script I want to find film by date.
If I search films of an exacly year, for example:

```
my $query = "//collection/film[date = 2012]";
```

it works exactly and return all films of 2012 year, but if I search all film before a year, it didn't work, for example:

```
my $query = "//collection/film[date < 2012]";
```

it returns all film..

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347320/xpath-dates-comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as usual, there's more than one way to do it. ) Either you let XPath tool know that it should compare dates (it doesn't know from the start) with something like this:

```
my $query = '//collection/film[xs:date(./date) < xs:date("2012-01-01")]';
```

... or you just bite the bullet and just compare the 'yyyy' substrings:

```
my $query = '//collection/film[substring(date, 1, 4) < "2012"]';
```

The former is better semantically, I suppose, but requires an advanced XML parser tool which supports XPath 2.0. And the latter was successfully verified with XML::XPath.

**UPDATE:** I'd like to give my explanation of why your first query works. ) See, you don't compare dates there - you compare numbers, but only because of '=' operator. Quote from [the doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans):

> When neither object to be compared is a node-set and the operator is =
> or !=, then the objects are compared by converting them to a common
> type as follows and then comparing them. If at least one object to be
> compared is a boolean, then each object to be compared is converted to
> a boolean as if by applying the boolean function. Otherwise, if at
> least one object to be compared is a number, then each object to be
> compared is converted to a number as if by applying the number
> function.

See? Your '2012-09-24' was converted to number - and became 2012. Which, of course, is equal to 2012. )

This doesn't work with any other comparative operators, though: that's why you need to either use substring, or convert the date-string to number. I supposed the first approach would be more readable - and faster as well, perhaps. )

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath, to check the year

```
//collection/film[substring-before(date, '-') &lt; '2012']
```

Your Perl script will be,

```
my $query = "//collection/film[substring-before(date, '-') &lt; '2012']";
```

OR

```
my $query = "//collection/film[substring-before(date, '-') = '2012']";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply use**:

```
//collection/film[translate(date, '-', '') < 20120101]
```

This removes the dashes from the date then compares it for being less than 2012-01-01 (with the dashes removed).

**In the same way you can get all films with dates prior a  given date** (not only year):

```
//collection/film[translate(date, '-', '') < translate($theDate, '-', '']
```